Total and Active users spike on iOS in Firebase from last one month. Ex: same userID with 3 different devices and 3 active sessions
Active users duplicated on iOS (not on android) in Firebase from last one month. Ex: For One userID with the report is showing Total users:2 and Active Users: 3 with different device types like
3 different device type and 3 active sessions showing in the report. Ideally it should be One userID, One device and One Session.
How to further investigate this issue.
Compared reports for last 3 months and found that for example for the same UserID, Total users:1 and Active Users:1 which is correct. and now its showing same UserID Total users:2 and Active Users: 3

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First you make sure that you have some real users. I always had a collection of five or six iPhones of all ages, so I could be five or six users, so I knew exactly how often each user should exist.
My wife uses an iPad and an iPhone, she would likely be there twice. That’s not uncommon but not the majority of cases. So some cases are normal and should be handled without problems. Find out what happens if a user buys a new iPhone, initialises it with the data from the old phone, and puts the old phone in a drawer.
But if you think your data is wrong then figure out in your code what exactly changes the total and active user count. And try what happens with the phones that you control.
